# Wordpress custom post type not showing the custom category in front end

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-taxonomy

I have some trouble with my custom posts an taxonomies. It displays all my custom posts perfect when I call *`url/team`*, but when I want call a category page for example "labor" like *`url/team/labor`*, the I get an 404.

Here is the registration of the custom post type and taxonomy in my plugin file:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                  => 'Team',
    'singular_name'         => 'Team-Mitglied',
    'add_new'               => 'Neues Team-Mitglied',
    'add_new_item'          => 'Hinzufügen',
    'edit_item'             => 'Team-Mitglied bearbeiten',
    'new_item'              => 'Neues Team-Mitglied',
    'all_items'             => 'Alle Team-Mitglieder',
    'view_item'             => 'Team-Mitglied anzeigen',
    'search_items'          => 'Team-Mitglied suchen',
    'not_found'             => 'Team-Mitglied nicht gefunden',
    'not_found_in_trash'    => 'Team-Mitglied nicht im Papierkorb gefunden',
    'parent_item_colon'     => '',
    'menu_name'             => 'Team',
);

$args = array( 
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'description'           => 'Team-Mitglieder erstellen und verwalten',
    'hierarchical'          => true,        
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'thumbnail','editor'),
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'menu_position'         => 25,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,       
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'query_var'             => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'rewrite'               => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'menu_icon'             => plugins_url( '../img/icon.png',__FILE__),
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'team' )

);

register_post_type( 'team_manager', $args );
flush_rewrite_rules();  // renew the rewrite rules

//register custom category for the team manager
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'Abteilungen',
    'singular_name'              => 'Abteilung',
    'search_items'               => 'Abteilung suchen',
    'popular_items'              => 'Beliebteste Abteilungen',
    'all_items'                  => 'Alle Abteilungen',
    'parent_item'                => null,
    'parent_item_colon'          => null,
    'edit_item'                  => 'Abteilung bearbeiten',
    'update_item'                => 'Abteilung aktualisieren',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Neue Abteilung',
    'new_item_name'              => 'Neuer Abteilungsname',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Abteilungen durch Komma trennen',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Abteilungen hinzufügen oder entfernen',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Aus den meist genutzten Abteilungen wählen',
    'not_found'                  => 'Keine Abteilung gefunden',
    'menu_name'                  => 'Abteilungen',
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'abteilungen' )
);

register_taxonomy( 'team_groups', 'team_manager', $args );
```

This is the part of my `archive-team_manager.php`:

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'team_manager',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'team_groups',
        ),
        'nopaging' => true,
    ));

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
            <div class="team-member">
                <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="team-member-pic">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'full', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- END .team-member-pic -->

                <div class="team-member-meta">
                    <?php 
                    $prename = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'td-staff-prename', true );
                    if(! empty($prename)) {
                        echo '<span class="team-member-prename">' . $prename . '</span><br />';
                    }

                    $name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'td-staff-name', true );
                    if(! empty($name)) {
                        echo '<span class="team-member-name">' . $name . '</span>';
                    }

                    $td_staff_function = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'td-staff-function', true );
                    if(! empty($td_staff_function)) {
                        echo '<p class="team-member-function">' . $td_staff_function . '</p>';
                    }?>
                </div><!-- END .team-member-meta -->

                <div class="team-member-desc">
                        <?php 
                        $td_staff_job_training = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'td-staff-job-training', true );
                        if(! empty($td_staff_job_training)) {
                            echo "<p><strong>Berufsausbildung:</strong> " . $td_staff_job_training . "</p>";
                        }?>

                        <?php 
                        $td_staff_service_area = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'td-staff-service-area', true );
                        if(! empty($td_staff_service_area)) {
                            echo "<p><strong>Arbeitsbereich:</strong> " . $td_staff_service_area . "</p>";
                        }?>

                        <?php 
                        $td_staff_employment_since = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'td-staff-employment-since', true );
                        if(! empty($td_staff_employment_since)) {
                            echo "<p><strong>Beschäftigt seit:</strong> " . $td_staff_employment_since . "</p>";
                        }?>

                        <?php 
                        $td_staff_birthday = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'td-staff-birthday', true );
                        if(! empty($td_staff_birthday)) {
                            echo "<p><strong>Geburtsdatum:</strong> " . $td_staff_birthday . "</p>";
                        }?>
                </div><!-- END .team-member-desc -->
            </div><!-- END .team-member -->
        <?php   
        }

    else :
        get_template_part( '/partials/content', 'not-found' );
    endif;
```

I tried it with an `taxonomy.php` but that doesn't worked as well. I read all the wordpress-codex about this but I'm really wondering why it doesn't work! I need an url-structure for my custom category archives like this:

`url/team`           (all of the posts from my custom post type) *done*
`url/team/labor`     (all of the post from my custom post type an a specific custom category)             *404 Error*

Finally I hope that you guys have a little clue for me :)

Comment: Why do you want to call taxonomy? Do you want to list all taxonomy in a page or anything extra?

Comment: Hallo Arshad, I need to display the custom category in an archive so that i can display the staff members in departments which is represented by an category.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$terms = get_terms( 'your_own_taxonomy_name', array(
                    'orderby'    => 'count',
                    'hide_empty' => 0,
                  ) );

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
       $args = array(
                     'post_type' => 'your_own_post_type_name',
                     'order' => 'DESC'
                    );
       $query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
       echo $term->name;
      }
```

Comment: And this is for the taxonomy.php?

Comment: really cool! that lists me all my custom categories what i need later in my plugin :D But now I need an category archive page with the url structure like in my post.